# Is there any rails gem for avatar selection?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

When user upload an image, I want to let user be able to use a rectangle to select an area to be there avatar.

Is there any existing rails gem or jQuery library for it?

Comment: There is a lot. Look at this link: http://www.downloadjavascripts.com/Image_Croppers.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a relevant railscast: http://railscasts.com/episodes/182-cropping-images

> In this episode we’re going to use Paperclip and a jQuery plugin called Jcrop to crop images on a web page.