# Rails: Select Avatar From Table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, user-profile, avatar

In the rails application I am developing, I want the to give the end users the ability to select an avatar. Nothing unusual here.

Unfortunately, I have found numerous articles, posts and gems about the uploading and selection of images (example: [Is there any rails gem for avatar selection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9957937/is-there-any-rails-gem-for-avatar-selection) | http://rubygems.org/gems/paperclip ) but what I want is for them to select from an 'Avatar' table in my database.  I do not want them to be able to upload anything.  The Avatars which they can select from will be created for them.

My thought is that the Avatar table would have two columns: id and url_path.

In their user profile I would have a field I assume to store the avatar_id -- but from there I am stuck --- I want them to see the gallery of avatars and make a selection to populate that field.  I am open to a gem -- but most seem more complex than I need.

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's some input to push you in the right direction. I don't think you need a gem for this.

You need three models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :avatar, through: :profile_picture
  has_one :profile_picture
  # change both associations to has many if a user can have multiple avatars
end

class Avatar < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :profile_picture
  # attribute: filename
end

class ProfilePicture < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :avatar
  # attributes: user_id and avatar_id
end
```

The profile picture model links users with avatars.

Since the user will only be able to choose from a set of avatars, you simply create the avatars as admin. Just put avatar images in assets/images/avatars and create the avatar records in the database yourself:

```
# assuming an avatar's filename is avatar.png
Avatar.create(filename: 'avatar.png')
# and make sure you have such an image in assets/images/avatars
```

Then, assuming you have a page where you render all avatars as, e.g., linked images as preview that users can click on to select one, you could simply link those images to a ProfilePicturesController's create action. You will need the following route

```
resources :profile_pictures, only: [ :create ]
```

and the following erb code for your images for the user to choose from:

```
<% Avatar.all.each do |a| %>
  <%= link_to image_tag("assets/images/avatars/#{a.filename}"), profile_pictures_path(avatar_id: a.id), method: :post %>
<% end %>
```

and the following controller code:

```
class ProfilePicturesController < ActionController::Base
  def create
    ProfilePicture.create(
      avatar_id: params[:avatar_id],
      user_id: current_user.id         # or however you retrieve the current user
    )
    flash[:notice] = 'Avatar updated.' # just a suggestion
    redirect_to :back                  # just a suggestion
  end
end
```

Haven't actually tried any of this, so let me know if it works.

Comment: After following th above -- I get this error `Expected c:xxx/app/controllers/profilepictures_controller.rb to define ProfilepicturesController`  I have re-reviewed the code but cannot seem to spot the problem and I also Googled the error message but could not find a solution.  One item of note -- I did have to change slightly your code removing the `profile_pictures` and changing them to `profilepictures` -- but I do not think that is the problem because the error is occurring after it has seen the routes file -- it appears to be happening right at the end ---

Comment: In Googling it, I think this is the clearest explanation: http://thinkrelevance.com/blog/2008/02/08/troubleshooting-loaderrors-in-rails-tests but not sure on how to overcome the error ---

Comment: It's asking you to define `ProfilepicturesController`, but instead you have `ProfilePicturesController` (notice the capital p in the middle). That actually makes a difference. Probably you did `rails g controller profilepictures` instead of `rails g controller profile_pictures`. Redo the whole thing and you should be good.

Comment: Last and really dumb question:  How do I display it for the current user?

Comment: `image_tag("/assets/images/avatars/#{current_user.profile_picture.filename}")`. Although you should definitely put that path in a user instance method.

Comment: Come to think of it, a helper method would be better.

Comment: when I do this:  `<%= image_tag("/assets/images/avatars/#{current_user.profile_picture.filename}") %>` I get this error:  `undefined method `filename' for "#<ProfilePicture:0x3ff3ee8>":ProfilePicture`

Comment: For anyone who may come across this question, I figured it out using this:  `<%= image_tag("/assets/images/avatars/#{current_user.avatar.filename}") %>`